# Are these packages not available?

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm currently trying to download some of the packages [here](https://www.statsresearch.co.nz/dsh/sslib/), though it mentions that they're not available in R when I type for example, `install.packages("ssM8")` into the console.

Now, it doesn't look like these packages are deprecated, as the [pdf](https://www.statsresearch.co.nz/dsh/sslib/) for the package `ssNZ` has been updated since yesterday, although, I cannot seem to install this also.

Perhaps, there is another method for installing these packages? I appreciate your comments, as I may have missed something out.

Comment: there was a comment here a second ago that https://www.statsresearch.co.nz/dsh/sslib/install.html#packages says you need `repos <- c("http://www.statsresearch.co.nz/dsh/sslib/r-repo",  "http://cran.r-project.org")`

Comment: @BenBolker Gotcha! just figured it out